# Pynput causes memory leaks

Tags: python, pynput

This is my code

```
def on_press(key):
    pass

def on_release(key):
    if(key==Key.pause):
        sys.exit()
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    if(key==Key.scroll_lock):
        myText=simpledialog.askstring("Replacement", "Enter your order ID:")
        loginFunction(myText)     
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

Whenever I try to write something my system keeps lagging.

Comment: You are creating a brand new Tk environment for every keypress, whether you're going to use it for anything or not.  Of course this makes your system lag!

Comment: I think there’s a popular post on here about having multiple instances of Tk, although I sadly can’t find it right now. Also, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style, you appear to be mixing multiple different conventions.